# What is the proper python way to write methods that only take a particular type?

Tags: python

I have a function that is supposed to take a string, append things to it where necessary, and return the result.

My natural inclination is to just return the result, which involved string concatenation, and if it failed, let the exception float up to the caller. However, this function has a default value, which I just return unmodified.

My question is: What if someone passed something unexpected to the method, and it returns something the user doesn't expect? The method should fail, but how to enforce that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not necessary to do so, but if you want you can have your method raise a `TypeError` if you know that the object is of a type that you cannot handle. One reason to do this is to help people to understand why the method call is failing and to give them some help fixing it, rather than giving them obscure error from the internals of your function.

Some methods in the standard library do this:

```
>>> [] + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use decorators for this kind of thing, you can see an example [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/454322-type-checking-decorator/).

But forcing parameters to be of a specific type isn't very pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Python works under the assumption that we are all intelligent adults that *read the documentation*. If you still want to do it, you should not assert the actual type, but rather just catch the exception when the argument does not support the operations you need, like that:

```
def foo(arg):
    try:
        return arg + "asdf"
    except TypeError:
        return arg
```

Comment: Exception catchalls are bad form; better to say 'except TypeError' here.

Answer (score 0):

What does the default value have to do with it? Are you saying you want to return the default value in the case where the caller doesn't pass a str? In that case:

```
def yourFunc( foo ):
    try:
        return foo + " some stuff"
    except TypeError:
        return "default stuff"
```

Space_C0wb0y has the right answer if you want to return the arg unmodified if it's not a string, and there's also the option of making an attempt to convert something to a string:

```
def yourFunc2( bar ):
    return str(bar) + " some stuff"
```

Which will work with a lot of different types.